Disable system spell-check on Ubuntu 24.04
I started using Proton Mail desktop app on Ubuntu 24.04 and I want to disable spell check in the app. However they say, that the app doesn't support disabling spell check, as it depends on my system settings. Is it possible to disable it on Ubuntu?
I tried some snippets from ChatGPT including removal of Anspell and Hunspell, but it resulted in destroying my GNOME environment which I had to reinstall.
I tried:

Language settings
It looks like I can't perform the following instruction:
"In the Language section, click on the Input Sources section."

Region and language settings:




gsettings
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-enable-input-feedback false

It returns: No such key "gtk-enable-input-feedback"


Also in dconf editor I cannot see this option.

does this article provide a solution?

I posted a screenshot below, it looks like it's different for me than in the post

the second answer in the linked article which refers to using terminal to invoke dconf reset -f /org/gnome/desktop/interface/ is the one you need. You should not use answer to add content to your question - only do that by [edit]

You're right, I should have edited the original post. Btw. I tried to deal with gsettings however I don't have this specific key in it

seems it is deprecated see Gtk Settings

Indeed. Does anyone know another solution which can actually disable the spell check?
